# Web USB: An operation that changes interface state is in progress error

Tags: javascript, navigator, webusb

Suddenly I get an error on a web usb device that connects with my Angular app.
The error reads: `An operation that changes interface state is in progress`.

**Edit**: more code:

### Selecting device & opening connection:

```
getDeviceSelector() {
  return navigator.usb
    .requestDevice(this.options)
    .then((selectedDevice) => {
        this.device = selectedDevice;
        return this.device.open(); // Begin a session.
    });
}
```

### Communicating with the device (Raspberry Pi)

Start communication with the web-usb on the Pi:

```
connectedDevice
.then(() => this.device.selectConfiguration(1)) // Select configuration #1 for the device.
.then(() => this.device.claimInterface(0)) // Request exclusive control over interface #0.
.then(() => {
    // Read data every 40 ms
    this.interval = interval(40).subscribe(async () => {
        await this.read();
    });
})
```

Handle the reading of all the data that is being send:

```
async read() {
  const result = await this.readOneLine();
  this.readCallbacks.forEach((callback) => {
    callback(result);
  });
}

readOneLine() {
  return this.device.transferIn(1, 8 * 1024).then(
    (result) => {
      return new Uint8Array(result.data.buffer);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }
  );
}
```

From there on, we use the `readCallbacks` function to pass the data we got from to device to a custom event that is been fired.

The error might be related to the new Chrome update, but I can not find changes to the `navigator.usb` or any other USB related mechanics.

New info will be added as soon as I have it!

Comment: Please include the code for communicating with the device in addition to the code for selecting the device and opening the connection. The "interface state change" error message is thrown when there is a call like `claimInterface()` that is currently in progress (i.e. the Promise hasn't resolved) and you make another call that would affect the same interface such a a `selectAlternativeInterface()` or `transferIn/Out()` on one of the interface's endpoints.

Comment: @ReillyGrant I added some details on how we handle the data from the Pi. I noticed that I'm also using `navigator.usb.addEventListener('connect', () => {`. Might that be an issue? I use it to handle a connection when a user has already permitted access to the usb devices in the browser.

Comment: Can you figure out which call is failing? That should help narrow down the source of the issue. I notice that you don't have any `catch()` blocks in your code.

Comment: The error starts in `getDeviceSelector` (first code block). The reason for the lack of catch blocks, is the fact that I am continuing this project after a colleague started it.
The thing is also, it worked fine and suddenly it stopped working (it is an experimental feature after all), but I can not find any change logs on the specs or in Chrome release notes...

Comment: Let's assume this is a regression in Chrome 90. Please file an issue report on crbug.com and we can continue to investigate there.

Comment: It will be really helpful for you to add calls to catch() so that we can figure out which call is actually rejecting a Promise. Nothing in getDeviceSelector() should be doing that.

Comment: I do recall a recent bug which caused claimInterface() to never resolve under certain conditions on Windows. As your code is written however I don't see how that could cause the error you are seeing since read() is not called until the Promise returned by claimInterface() resolves.

Comment: So we found the solution: if you safely remove the usb-device and than plug it in another port, than all works as expected...
So it seems like the weird Windows-error you mentioned. Still not sure if I should delete this question or answer it so people won't have the error again...

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as the answer. If you can still trigger the issue by moving the device to the old port it would still be very useful to figure out which function call in your code is actually triggering the error so I can understand what state the device has gotten into and potentially develop a solution to the underlying issue.

Comment: Okay, if I find any more related params, I will let you know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem only occurred on **some Windows laptops**. I had to **#1 safely remove the USB-device** and **#2 plug it in another port**. After that, the connection was normal just like before (also on the original USB-port).

It suddenly happened on different computers and at the same time, but we were unable to see the exact environment that caused this issue.